# How do I save a form to an image file in vb.net?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, forms, winforms, cefsharp

How do I save the current form to an image in vb.net without taking a screenshot. I would like the user to have the option to use a save file dialog to choose their file name, and if necessary I will resort to taking a screenshot, but I would prefer not to.

So far I am using CefSharp in WinForms and passing a private class to the javascript/html side of my program. When the user clicks on an html button to save an image this calls a method inside of the aforementioned class which should open up a save file dialog to draw the image.

I've tried methods that include taking a screenshot, but for obvious reasons, I cannot use a save file dialog because that hides the frame I am trying to take an image of. Maybe there is a work around to this that I am not seeing.

I have tried other methods that involve creating a Graphics object, but they always return a blank image. I saw a post somewhere saying not to use the CreateGraphics() function, but instead to use a picture box event. I am not sure how to properly call a picture box that exists within the current form from a private class(The class which is passed to javascript I have defined as a private class in the same .vb file as my form's vb code)

```
Public Sub saveImage(dataURL As String, format As String)
            Dim t As New Thread(Sub()
                                    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
                                    sfd.Filter = "Png Image|*.png|Jpeg Image|*.jpeg| Jpg Image|*.jpg"
                                    sfd.Filter = format + " Image|" + "*." + format.ToLower()
                                    sfd.Title = "Save Plot Image."
                                    sfd.FilterIndex = 2

                                    If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then



                                        ' Dim array As String() = dataURL.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                        ' Dim byteArray As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(array.GetValue(1))
                                        ' Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(byteArray)
                                        ' Dim image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
                                        ' Image.Save(sfd.FileName)

                                        Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(frmGraph.Width, frmGraph.Height)
                                        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, frmGraph.Width, frmGraph.Height)
                                        frmGraph.DrawToBitmap(bm, rect)
                                        bm.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png)



                                    End If
                                End Sub)
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
            t.Start()
            t.Join()



The code I have defined above is a public sub within a private class. The code saves an image file, but the file is blank.
```

Comment: Why all the the tags; the only code I am seeing is `vb.net`... Also more than likely you will need to use `user32` to call the function `GetActiveWindow`.

Comment: Dialogs should be opened on the UI thread, not a separate thread.  Using BitBlt worked previously see https://gist.github.com/jankurianski/f3419d4580517516c24b for an example

Comment: Alternatively you enable remote debugging and use puppeteer.

Comment: I usually get the rect of handle of myForm with api GetWindowRect, and then calculate width and height from the rect to assign bmp, last I take the picture of form: myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp): myGraphics.CopyFromScreen(myRect.Left + 7, myRect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size). Then I can save the bmp to my file.

Comment: without api getwindowrect, I directly go to: set the bitmap with Me.Width, Me.Height, set Graphics FromImage of  a bitmap: and do CopyFromScreen(Me.Left + 7, Me.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size) by the graphics

Comment: the first method, just if I create it as separate exe file, for example, FormPreview.exe, and I send the handle to the exe from myform, Shell("FormPreview.exe " & Me.Handle.ToString, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, 1000).